# File path issues in R using Windows ("Hex digits in character string ...) VersionXY

Tags: r

I have this issue already mentioned by many. My R code worked on a computer at my previous job (with \s), but does not work any more on a new computer

My case is that R is returning this message:

Error: '\U' used without hex digits in character string starting "'C:\U" ,

even when there are actually no "\" in code. I have tried all the options suggested in previous posts (i.e. \, /, //, \\, ////), but it does not work.

I use R version 3.4.1 (2017-6-30) and Office 2016.

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think you should also post the relevant R code, but using forward slashes instead of backslashes might fix it.

Comment: I think that's the answer (and a proper question to your problem): https://stackoverflow.com/a/77863036/10320202

Comment: Plus: Possible solution number 2: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77868620/10320202

Answer (score 0):

One way to get around file path issues in R is to use forward slashes in your path, e.g.

```
U:/path/to/file.ext
```