# R error: '\U' used without hex digits in character string starting "'C:\U"

Tags: r

Upon start up, when I run Rstudio I get the following error message:

```
 Error: '\U' used without hex digits in character string starting "'C:\U"
```

This is not an issue when trying to run scripts within Rstudio. However, this error prevents me from running any R script as a local job or outside of RStudio.

I unistalled and reinstalled R 4.0.0 and I am still seeing the same error. When I restart R this is how it appears in the console..

```
Restarting R session...

Error: '\U' used without hex digits in character string starting "'C:\U"
```

I do not have any paths in my Rscript or Rprofile. I tried setting my working directory in my Rprofile and it did not remove the error. Any ideas?

Comment: Use forward slash for file path, something like `C:/Users/XXX/XXX/...`.

Comment: Where? I do not have any file paths. This is just upon start up. Not when running script. All of my file paths in any actual scripts have "/"

Comment: When I restart R studio I see this in the terminal:

Restarting R session...

Error: '\U' used without hex digits in character string starting "'C:\U"

Comment: You need double or possibly triple backslashes because the first one gets escaped

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and after I deleted .Rprofile and .radian_history from my user directory, the error message disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and this is how I solved it.

## Solution 1: Check .Rprofile

(I also answered it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77868620/10320202)):

In the .Rprofile file in "C:\Users\myusername\Documents," I had the following content:

```
# LanguageServer Setup Start (do not change this chunk)
# to remove this, run languageserversetup::remove_from_rprofile
if (requireNamespace('languageserversetup', quietly = TRUE)) {
  options(langserver_library = 'C:\Users\myusername\Documents/languageserver-library')
  languageserversetup::languageserver_startup()
  unloadNamespace('languageserversetup')
}
# LanguageServer Setup End
```

So, there were incorrect slashes in options(langserver_library = 'C:\Users\myusername\Documents/languageserver-library').

Check if your file has similar problems. If yes, you should replace \ with /.

Also, check for your .Rprofile in your current folder.

## Solution 2: Check .libPaths

If Solution 1 does not work, check your `.libPaths()` for incorrect slashes.
I also answered it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77863036/10320202)