# Unable to install R package due to missing g++

Tags: r, rstudio, special-characters, backslash

I am trying to install the updates to the packages available in my RStudio, but I get the message as follows in the console:

> Error: '\U' used without hex digits in character string starting "'C:\U" 
> Using checkpoint directory C:/Apps/.checkpoint/2022-01-11/lib/x86_64-w64-mingw32/3.6.3 
> install.packages(c("boot", "brio", "cachem", "cli", "colorspace", "curl", "data.table", "diffobj", "digest", "dplyr", "fansi", "fs", "gert", "glue", "isoband", "later", "lattice", "Matrix", "mgcv", "mime", "nlme", "openssl", "pkgcache", "ragg", "Rcpp", "roxygen2", "stringi", "survival", "systemfonts", "testthat", "textshaping", "tibble", "tidyr", "utf8", "xfun", "xml2", "zip"), lib = "C:/Users/mrinmay.kalita/OneDrive - Shell/Documents/R/R-3.6.3/library") 
> Error in install.packages : Updating loaded packages

In which path do I make the correct change (i.e., replace \ with / or double forward slash as per *[R error: ‘\u’ used without hex digits in character string starting “”c:\u”](https://www.programmingr.com/r-error-messages/used-without-hex-digits-in-character-string-starting/)*) to fix this issue?

The RStudio version is 2022.07.1. I started as menu *Tools* → *Check for Package Updates* → *Select All* → *Install Updates*.

Comment: Did you see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44273571/starting-r-error-u-used-without-hex-digits-in-character-string-starting-c) ?

Comment: i changed the backward slashes in the path to an environment variable specified in my Rprofile to forward and it worked.