# "Error: '\U' used without hex digits in character string (<input>:4:36)" when opening R

Tags: error-handling

I am using R version 4.3.2 and whenever I open the program the following error message is shown:
Error: '\U' used without hex digits in character string (:4:36).

Might it be anything else in these directory paths which causes the error message?
I can still use R and Rstudio without problem but when I want to use R extension in Visual studio code this error message prevents me from using R and global environsments.

Regards
Andreas

In an earlier post regarding this issue it is recommended to changes all backslashed to forwardslashed in the file directory. [I get 'Error: '\U' used without hex digits in character string starting ""C:\U"' when starting R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44273571/i-get-error-u-used-without-hex-digits-in-character-string-starting-c-u)
However, this is my directory addresses currently:

> .libPaths()
> [1] "C:/Users/ap/AppData/Local/R/win-library/4.3"
> [2] "C:/Program Files/R/R-4.3.2/library"
> getwd()
> [1] "C:/Users/ap/Documents"

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve this issue by using the following command in the R terminal:
file.edit(file.path("~", ".Rprofile"))
and then add one additional backslash to the Rprofile directory.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).